# How to print EC2 Tag name along with IP address?

Tags: python, amazon-ec2, boto3

I have a code which prints the Public IP's for the running instances,

```
regions = ['us-east-1','us-west-1','us-west-2','eu-west-1','sa-east-1','ap-southeast-1','ap-southeast-2','ap-northeast-1']
for region in regions:
  client = boto3.client('ec2',aws_access_key_id=ACCESS_KEY,aws_secret_access_key=SECRET_KEY,region_name=region,)
  addresses_dict = client.describe_addresses()
  for eip_dict in addresses_dict['Addresses']:
      if 'PrivateIpAddress' in eip_dict:
          print eip_dict['PublicIp']
```

This is fine, now i also want to print the `tag name` and store it in another dict, i know i this can be done by :

```
regions = ['us-east-1','us-west-1','us-west-2','eu-west-1','sa-east-1','ap-southeast-1','ap-southeast-2','ap-northeast-1']
for region in regions:
  client = boto3.client('ec2',aws_access_key_id=ACCESS_KEY,aws_secret_access_key=SECRET_KEY,region_name=region,)
  dex_dict = client.describe_tags()
  for dexy_dict in dex_dict['Tags']:
     print dexy_dict['Value']
```

The problem is how do i combine it in one function and use 2 dict : one to store IP's and another to store the tag-name ? Please HELP

Comment: Are you looking for a dictionary with the structure {client:[IP, tag_name]}?

Comment: yes, but i need to be able to pass these values to another def , so please help me on how to return

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following code, it will give you a dictionary where the key is the `InstanceId` and the value is a list of `[PublicIP, Name]`.

```
import boto3

def instance_info():
    instance_information = {}
    ip_dict = {}
    client = boto3.client('ec2')
    addresses_dict = client.describe_addresses().get('Addresses')

    for address in addresses_dict:
        if address.get('InstanceId'):
            instance_information[address['InstanceId']] = [address.get('PublicIp')]

    dex_dict = client.describe_tags().get('Tags')
    for dex in dex_dict:
        if instance_information.get(dex['ResourceId']):
            instance_information[dex['ResourceId']].append(dex.get('Value'))

    for instance in instance_information:

        if len(instance_information[instance]) == 2:
            ip_dict[instance_information[instance][0]] = instance_information[instance][1]
        else:
            ip_dict[instance_information[instance][0]] = ''
    return instance_information, ip_dict
```

Comment: Throws me :

`Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "stackHELP.py", line 10, in <module>
    instance_information[address['InstanceId']] = [address.get('PublicIp')]
KeyError: 'InstanceId'
, ` 

i.e a check on instance id should be there , and does this returns only the RUNNING instances??

Comment: I tried the function with my AWS instances and I only got the running ones.

Comment: i got something like :

`{}
{'i-93cd0221': ['54.21.1.22', 'email-relay']}
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "stackHELP.py", line 11, in <module>
    instance_information[address['InstanceId']] = [address.get('PublicIp')]
KeyError: 'InstanceId'`

Comment: I modified the function accordingly.

Comment: cool, this works, now what is the way if i want to access the IP or the instance tag because i need to pass the IP from the returned code to other code

Comment: now it also returns a dictionary where the key is the IP address and the value is the name. You can also reverse it, if this more helpful for you.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/114092/discussion-between-pythonfreak-and-ashafix).